# Stanford CoreNLP merge tokens

Tags: token, stanford-nlp

I found the powerful [RegexNER](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/regexner.html) and it's superset [TokensRegex](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokensregex.html) from Stanford CoreNLP.
There are some rules that should give me fine results, like the pattern for PERSONs with titles:
"g. Meho Mehic" or "gdin. N. Neko" (g. and gdin. are abbrevs in Bosnian for mr.).

I'm having some trouble with existing tokenizer. It splits some strings on two tokens and some leaves as one, for example, token "g." is left as word `<word>g.</word>` and token "gdin." is split on 2 tokens: `<word>gdin</word>` and `<word>.</word>`.

That causes trouble with my regex, I have to deal with one-token and multi-token cases (note the two "maybe-dot"s), RegexNER example:

```
( /g\.?|gdin\.?/ /\./? ([{ word:/[A-Z][a-z]*\.?/ }]+) ) PERSON
```

Also, this causes another issue, with sentence splitting, some sentences are not well recognized so regex fails... For example, when a sentence contains "gdin." it will split it on two, so a dot will end the (non-existing) sentence. I managed to bypass this with `ssplit.isOneSentence = true` for now.

Questions:

1. Do I have to make my own tokenizer, and how? (to merge some tokens like "gdin.")
2. Are there any settings I missed that could help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I thought about this for a bit and can actually think of something pretty straight forward for your case.  One thing you could do is add "gdin" to the list of titles in the tokenizer.

The tokenizer rules are in edu.stanford.nlp.process.PTBLexer.flex (look at line 741)

I do not really understand the tokenizer that well, but clearly there are a list of job titles in there, so they must be cases where it will not split off the period.

This will of course require you to work with a custom build of Stanford CoreNLP.

You can get the full code at our GitHub:https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP

There are instructions on the main page for building a jar with all of the main Stanford CoreNLP classes.  I think if you just run the ant process it will automatically generate the new PTBLexer.java based on PTBLexer.flex.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about this myself yesterday. It would be nice if the tokenizer could be parametrized with some of this stuff... :D

Comment: I've made itttttttt, thanks once again! :D There's task called `flexeverything` in `build.xml`. I just needed to replace old jar with this new one.

Comment: Also I am unable to get answer to this important corenlp question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39688652/german-corenlp-model-defaulting-to-english-models